# IBM 3624 Pin Offset Generation

Tags: java, cryptography

I am working on Pin Generation with IBM 3624 algorithm, and then an Offset from it. Here is the algorithm from [IBM Website](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.csfb400/csfb4za2597.htm):

I am not sure about the order, the Input data has to be used. For example, the algorithm requires validation data (Start Pos, Length, PAN Pad Character & Pin Length), a Decimalization table (0123456789012345), a Pin, Pan & PDK.

Edit: Here is the Input Data format - 
PAN (Account Number or Card Number) : 16 Digit Hex String.
Pin (Usually 4 digits, but can be changed upon requirements) : 4 Digit numeric (Hex values to be replaced from Decimalization Table)
PDK (Encrypted Key supplied with PAN) : 32 Digit numeric

Start Position & Length : Digits to be selected from PAN, the last digit is check digit and will be ignored. These selected digits of PAN are later padded back to 16 digits.

Pad Char: single Char (A Hex Digit).

And here is the code I am using to do this:

```
public static void CalculatePINOffset(String PAN, String Pin, String PDKkey, String DecTab, int StartPos, int Length,
        char PadChar) throws Exception{
    int PANLength = PAN.length();
    if(Length != (PANLength - StartPos)){
        throw new Exception(
                "Invalid 'Start Pos and Length' format.");
    }
    //Padding the PAN before Start POS with Pad Chars back to 16 digits.
    String block = ISOUtil.padleft(PAN.substring(StartPos, Length + (StartPos - 1)), PAN.length(), PadChar);

    /*
     * Doing encryption stuff on block with PDKKey. 
     * The execute function basically encrypts block and PDKKey, and any algorithm could do the work. 
     */
    String result = execute(block , PDKkey, "2TDES");

    Map<Character, Character> decTab = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
    decTab.put('A', '0');
    decTab.put('B', '1');
    decTab.put('C', '2');
    decTab.put('D', '3');
    decTab.put('E', '4');
    decTab.put('F', '5');

    //Replacing Hex Characters with numbers from Decmalization table.
    char[] Inpin = result.substring(0, 4).toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < Inpin.length; i++){
        if(decTab.containsKey(Inpin[i])){
            Inpin[i] = decTab.get(Inpin[i]);
        }
    }
    result = new String(Inpin);
    System.out.println("Intermediate PIN: "+result);

    //Calculating offset from Intermediate Pin.
    int[] Offset = new int[4];
    int Cpin;
    int Ipin;
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++){
        Ipin = Integer.parseInt(result.substring(i, i+1));
        Cpin = Integer.parseInt(Pin.substring(i, i+1));

        if((Cpin - Ipin) >= 0){
            Offset[i] = (Cpin - Ipin);
        }
        else{
            Offset[i] = (Ipin - Cpin)%10;
        }
    }

    String PinOffset = Arrays.toString(Offset);
    System.out.println("Pin Offset: " + PinOffset);
}
```

Note: I am not looking for code or implementation. I provided this snippet of code to better explain the order of usage. All that could help me is the correct order of encryption, usage of Validation data & Decimalization table.

When cross checked with open source tools like BP - Tools, the offset and pin generated are not matching. Where did I went wrong?

Comment: And without any input or output values nor the external functions, we are expected to help you how exactly?

Comment: @owlstead Edited. Please check my requirements now, and let me know if any information related to this is missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I figured it out. If someone is looking for the same, here is the process to do it:

```
1. Generate validation data from PAN:
   - Get PAN Digits from Start Position to Length, and add Pad characters to the right, until it was 16 digits in length.
2. Encrypt validation data with pdk key using DES, 3DES or AES algorithm. This will generate an encrypted code.
3. Decimalize encrypted code using decimalization table.
4. Convert to Hex String, and get the first n digits (n = pin length). This will generate intermediate Pin.
5. Finally, Modulo Subtract intermediate pin with customer pin. This generates the Offset.
```

Hope this helps.
- Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an implementation?

Answer (score 1):

**The issues are two:**

1. The modulus subtraction is wrong
2. The data validation starts from the rightmost digit before the check
   digit.

```
public String calculateOffset(String pin, String pan, String pvk) throws Exception{
       System.out.println("CryptoProcessor.calculateOffset");
       Map decTab = Arrays.asList("0:0", "1:1", "2:2", "3:3", "4:4", "5:5","6:6", "7:7", "8:8", "9:9","A:0", "B:1", "C:2", "D:3", "E:4", "F:5")
           .stream()
           .map(elem -> elem.split(":"))
           .filter(elem -> elem.length==2)
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e[0], e -> e[1]));
       if(pan.length() = 0){
               Offset[i] = (Cpin - Ipin);
           }else{
               Offset[i] = (Cpin + 10 - Ipin);
           }
       }
       StringBuffer offset = new StringBuffer();
       IntStream.of(Offset).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(a -> offset.append(a.toString()));
       System.out.println("Pin offset: " + offset.toString());
       return offset.toString();
   }

Pan:1234567899876543
Pin:3196
pvk:0123456789ABCDEFFEDCBA9876543210
Validation data 456789987654FFFF
Jan 28, 2017 4:13:23 PM com.ocularminds.oswitch.crypto.CryptoProcessor process
INFO: Data : 456789987654FFFF
encrypted data 3DE7489FEBC9340D
Intermediate PIN: 3347
Pin offset: 0859
```