# What does "EDE Multiple Encryption" mean in IBM 3624 encryption?

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm trying to implement IBM 3624 algorithm for PIN generation as described here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/3.1.0?topic=algorithms-3624-pin-generation-algorithm

[image]

However, I don't understand exactly what the "EDE" Multiple Encryption means.

I thought EDE would stand for Encrypt-Decrypt-Encrypt, but if I'm using the same 128-bits PIN Generation Key in every step, wouldn't I be getting the same result as if I encrypted once.

For validation, I'm following the code at: https://paymentcardtools.com/pin-verification/ibm-3624

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It will be good to ask this at [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) too

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849323/ibm-3624-pin-offset-generation/41911467  Look at IBM Website Link.

Comment: It probably stands for Triple DES in the encrypt-decrypt-encrypt configuration. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, I get it but I assume the TripleDES implementation of the .NET framework, which I'm using, already handles the triple encryption. I don't think I have to manually Encrypt-Decrypt-Encrypt, right?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit more of investigation, I can get sure that E-D-E stands for Encrypt-Decrypt-Encrypt, which are the typical steps performed in TripleDES.

What made me confused was that each implementation of this algorithm transformed the card number into the validation data in different ways and that's why I was seeing different results. But the encryption algorithm was not to blame. The encryption is plain and classic TripleDES and I don't need to reinvent the wheel there.

To clarify, you typically start from the card number (PAN) and create a 64 bits validation data from there. Normally, the PAN are 16-19 digits. If you trim it to 16 digits and interpret each digit as a Byte, you'll end up with 128 bits, so you have to reduce it to 64.

Some implementations interpret each digit as 4 bits and some use a compression algorithm to combine the nibbles to half. Moreover, some implementations discard the check digit and add a leading zero and some others discard the check digit and take only the 12 right-most digits, again padding with zeros.

So, my conclusion is that the validation data is whatever each implementation wants to define. Seems it's up to you how you want to come to a 64 bits quantity

The following is the C# in which I've been working, which reproduces the behavior of the Intermediate PIN Calculator at https://paymentcardtools.com/pin-verification/ibm-3624 (if you want to calculate the PIN Offset after this, you are just a couple of more steps away):

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Example parameters (replace with your actual values)
        string cardPAN = "4556238577532209"; // PAN: Primary Account Number
        string decimalizationTable = "0123456789012345";  // Decimalization Table
        int pinLength = 4;  // Desired PIN length
        string pgkString = "CB583B988F9BF191320B92FD6EF8254A"; // PGK (PIN Generation Key - 32 hex digits, 16 bytes, 128 bits

        // Convert PGK string to byte array
        byte[] pgk = HexStringToByteArray(pgkString);

        // Calculate Intermediate PIN
        string intermediatePIN = CalculateIntermediatePIN(cardPAN, decimalizationTable, pinLength, pgk);

        Console.WriteLine($"Intermediate PIN: {intermediatePIN}");
    }

    static string CalculateIntermediatePIN(string cardPAN, string decimalizationTable, int pinLength, byte[] pgk)
    {
        // Validate input lengths
        if (cardPAN.Length < 16 || decimalizationTable.Length != 16 || pgk.Length != 16)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid input lengths.");
        }

        // Step 1: Extract the account number from the PAN (digits 2-11)
        string accountNumber = cardPAN[..16];
        Console.WriteLine("PAN: {0}", accountNumber);

        // Step 2: Perform DES encryption using the PGK key
        string encryptedAccountNumber = EncryptDES(accountNumber, pgk);
        Console.WriteLine("Encrypted PAN: {0}", encryptedAccountNumber);
        
        // Step 3: Apply decimalization using the Decimalization Table
        string decimalizedAccountNumber = Decimalize(encryptedAccountNumber, decimalizationTable);
        Console.WriteLine("Decimalized: {0}", decimalizedAccountNumber);

        // Step 4: Extract the first 'pinLength' digits of the decimalized account number
        string intermediatePIN = decimalizedAccountNumber[..pinLength];

        return intermediatePIN;
    }

    static string Decimalize(string input, string decimalizationTable)
    {
        StringBuilder decimalizedResult = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            int digit = Convert.ToInt32(input[i].ToString(), 16);
            int decimalizedDigit = int.Parse(decimalizationTable[digit].ToString());
            decimalizedResult.Append(decimalizedDigit);
        }

        return decimalizedResult.ToString();
    }

    static string EncryptDES(string data, byte[] key)
    {
        // Convert the input data and key to byte arrays
        byte[] dataBytes = dataBytes = ConvertCardNumberToByteArray(data);

        // Create a new instance of the DESCryptoServiceProvider class
        using (var tdesProvider = TripleDES.Create())
        {
            // Set the key for the DES algorithm
            tdesProvider.Key = key;
            tdesProvider.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            tdesProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

            // Create a CryptoStream to perform DES encryption
            using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = tdesProvider.CreateEncryptor())
            {
                // Encrypt the data
                byte[] encryptedBytes = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);

                // Convert the encrypted bytes to a hex string
                string encryptedHex = BitConverter.ToString(encryptedBytes).Replace("-", "");

                return encryptedHex;
            }
        }
    }

    static byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
    {
        // Check if the hex string length is even
        if (hexString.Length % 2 != 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid hex string length.");
        }

        // Create a byte array to store the result
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];

        // Convert each pair of characters to a byte
        for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
        {
            byteArray[i] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
        }

        return byteArray;
    }

    static byte[] ConvertCardNumberToByteArray(string cardNumber)
    {
        // Check if the input string is valid
        if (cardNumber.Length != 16 || !IsNumeric(cardNumber))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid card number format");
        }

        // Create a byte array to store the result
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[8];

        // Iterate through the string and convert every two digits to a byte
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i += 2)
        {
            byte value = (byte)((HexValue(cardNumber[i]) << 4) | HexValue(cardNumber[i + 1]));
            byteArray[i / 2] = value;
        }

        return byteArray;
    }

    static int HexValue(char hexChar)
    {
        // Convert a hexadecimal character to its numeric value
        return int.Parse(hexChar.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    }

    static bool IsNumeric(string value)
    {
        // Check if a string consists of numeric characters
        foreach (char c in value)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(c))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```